# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, error-handling

total beginner following a tutorial on YoutTube here! I get the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () while trying to create a WhatsApp clone program and I have no idea why.
Here's the first part of the code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const PREFIX = 'whatsapp-clone-'

export default function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
    const prefixedKey = PREFIX + key

    const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        const jsonValue = localStorage.getItem(prefixedKey)

        if (jsonValue != null) return JSON.parse(jsonValue)
        if (typeof initialValue === 'function') {
            return initialValue()
        } else {
            return initialValue
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(prefixedKey, JSON.stringify(value))
    }, [prefixedKey, value])

    return [value, setValue]
}
```

And here's the other essential part:

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './Login'
import useLocalStorage from '../hooks/useLocalStorage';

function App() {
  const [id, setId] = useLocalStorage('id')

  return (
    <>
      {id}
      <Login onIdSubmit={setId} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Here's the first error I get, which I believe leads to the rest of them.
[image: errorimg1]

Thanks for any help, I spent like 2 hours googling to no avail.

Comment: What does `localStorage.getItem(prefixedKey)` return? Looks like it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Mohan I guess it returns 'whatsapp-clone-' (which is the PREFIX) and key, but I'm not sure what the key part is supposed to do, maybe it's the randomly generated ID?

Comment: If you run `localStorage.getItem('whatsapp-clone-id')` in the browser console, you can see what's stored in it.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Mohan When I run it inthe debugger it opens a chrome tab with the address localhost8080 and tells me it can't reach the site, I tried React dev tools chrome extension in the tab where I'm running the whole thing but that doesn't even do anything. Also, how would I run a short code snippet? I'm new to all this

Comment: You could either add `console.log(localStorage.getItem('whatsapp-clone-id'))` to your code or run it directly in the browser console.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Mohan I tried sticking it in different places and sometimes it returned 'undefined' in the console along with the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling `useLocalStorage('id')` without a second argument, `initialValue` is `undefined`.

```js
if (jsonValue != null) return JSON.parse(jsonValue)
if (typeof initialValue === 'function') {
  return initialValue()
} else {
  return initialValue // this lines gets executed when `jsonValue` is null
}
```

Initially, `localStorage` does not contain `whatsapp-clone-id` — `jsonValue` is `null` which causes the `else` block above to run, setting `value` to `undefined`. (`initialValue` is `undefined`)

```js
localStorage.setItem(prefixedKey, JSON.stringify(value))
```

And when the `useEffect` code runs, `'undefined'` is set in the `whatsapp-clone-id` key since `JSON.stringify(undefined)` is `undefined`. The error message says it couldn't parse the JSON on running `JSON.parse(jsonValue)` since the first character (at position 0) is `u` which is not valid JSON (The first character has to be `{`).

The fix is simple. Only set the value to `initialValue` if it's present. Otherwise, set it to `null` or `{}`.

```js
const jsonValue = localStorage.getItem(prefixedKey)
if (jsonValue != null) {
  return JSON.parse(jsonValue)
}
if (typeof initialValue === "function") {
  return initialValue()
}
if (initialValue) {
  return initialValue
}

return null
```

You'll have to run `localStorage.removeItem('whatsapp-clone-id')` before trying the new code.